# How to put html in a string in a key value pair for submission into a collection in meteor

Tags: javascript, video, meteor

I am trying to plase variable inside the src value of a video element, which is a string itself that is going to be inserted into a collection. I am not just storing the src value in the collection because I don't want ta empty video outputted if there is no video src.

I am currently getting a unexpected token.

```
'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var videoSrc = $(e.target).find('[name=video]').val()


    var post = {
      title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
      image: $(e.target).find('[name=image]').val(),
            content: $(e.target).find('[name=content]').val(),
            video: "<video  width='320' height='240' preload='auto' >
    <source src='"+ videoSrc +"' type='video/webm'>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>"



    };

    Meteor.call('postInsert', post, function(error, result) {
      // display the error to the user and abort
      if (error)
        return alert(error.reason);

                Session.update("imageId", null);
                Session.update("imageKey", null);
                Session.update("videoId", null);
                Session.update("videoKey", null);

      Router.go('postPage', {_id: result._id});
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this line results with undefined`video: "<video  width='320' height='240' preload='auto' >
    <source src='"+ videoSrc +"' type='video/webm'>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>"`

Good idea to do conditional objects is to make selector like:

```
var selector={};
selector.title= $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val();
selector.image= $(e.target).find('[name=image]').val();
selector.content= $(e.target).find('[name=content]').val();
if(videoSrc)
selector.video= "<video  width='320' height='240' preload='auto' >
    <source src='"+ videoSrc +"' type='video/webm'>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>";

var post=selector
```